# How to use method name as an argument

Tags: ruby

I have a method like this

```
def foo(method_name)
  bars.find{|bar| bar.method_name }
end
```

The argument `method_name` is a symbol and a method `method_name` returns boolean value.

Can I write this method by using `&:`? 
I want to write like:

```
bars.find("&:#{method_name}")
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: The method you _have_ won’t work already. `bars.find{|bar| bar.method_name }` might be rewritten as `bars.find(&:method_name)`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: surely you mean `bars.find(&method_name)`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev surely I didn’t :) `bars.find{|bar| bar.any? }` would be `bars.find(&:any?)`—you were confused by the name of `method_name` :)

Comment: @mudasobwa I think I was. There's no example call of `foo` so I couldn't tell what `method_name` is, but I assumed it's a method name. In which case, my example should work :)

Comment: `bars.find("&:#{method_name}")` – do you mean `bars.find(&:"#{method_name}")`?

Comment: Sorry for my ambiguous question. I added the details and accepted Zhong Zheng's answer.

Comment: @ironsand: if it's a symbol, then you wouldn't need to use `.to_sym`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
def foo(method_name)
  method_sym = method_name.to_sym
  bars.find(&method_sym)
end

# one line
def foo(method_name)
  bars.find(&method_name.to_sym)
end
```

or

```
def foo(method_name)
  bars.find{|bar| bar.public_send(method_name)}
end
```

Comment: How does this answer the question stated? Also, using `send` instead of `public_send` is a code smell.

Comment: I assumed the `method_name` is a string.

Comment: `"#{method_name}"` in assumption “the `method_name` is a string” is senseless.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I agree your comment `bars.find{|bar| bar.method_name } might be rewritten as bars.find(&:method_name)`. But given `method_name` is a variable passed in, I guess the author was trying to call the method by `method_name`. Your example in your comment is made on the assumption that `method_name` is already known.

Comment: If it is a name of the method, `bars.find &method_name` does the trick and answers the question stated.

Comment: I don't think it solves the question. `def foo(method_name)
  [2,4,3].find(&method_name)
end

puts foo('odd?')` raises `wrong type of argument type String (expected Proce) error`

Comment: If you want to pass string, call `to_sym` on it explicitly: `def foo(method_name) [2,4,3].find(&method_name.to_sym) end`. [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) is the One.